# Add class to selected div (div is not unique)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different `divs` that have an `id="item"`. When I select one of the `divs`, a new class should be added to `a` where the div has been selected. Is there any way to do this when the IDs are not unique?

HTML:

```
<div class="something" id="item">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript (what I have tried, but does not work):

```
// changes all links on the website
$("body").delegate('#item', 'click', function() {  
    $( "a" ).addClass( "active" );
});
```

Edit: I am using the `delegate` function because I create all the divs with PHP, otherwise the click event is not registered.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. jQuery stops searching after it finds the first matching element.

Comment: `id` is a **unique** attribute. There should **never** be two elements with the same ID.

Comment: That should work fine, as long as you replace `"a"` with `"a",this`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ever have a non-unique ID, that is not valid. Invalid IDs aside, this was not working since you were using `$("a")` which targets all the links, rather than a specific one.

HTML:

```
<div class="something" id="item1">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item2">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item3">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item4">
   <a href="#" class="something">...</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
// I doubt your actual site uses something in both cases,
// but I made this more explicit.
$("body").on( 'div.something', 'click', function() {  

    $('.active').removeClass( 'active' );

    // Use this to add active to div
    $( this ).addClass( "active" );

    // Use this to add active to link
    $( this ).find( 'a' ).addClass('active");

});
```

Also note I changed `delegate` to `on` assuming you are using latest version of jQuery - if not go back to `delegate`

Answer (score 1):

$(this).find("a").addClass("active");

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for, and the only solution that has been presented that works until now. Thanks rbginge!

Comment: How come my solution doesn't work? This code also doesn't handle the invalid IDs nor the fact that clicking multiple divs will keep active on all of them.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
<div class="something" id="item1">
   <a href="#" class="otherthing">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item2">
   <a href="#" class="otherthing">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item3">
   <a href="#" class="otherthing">...</a>
</div>
<div class="something" id="item4">
   <a href="#" class="otherthing">...</a>
</div>



$(".something").on('click', '.otherthing', function() {  
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```